# Trying to create an input search that filters text with conjunction and disjunction JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I used jquery mobile to filter a div that contains a few paragraphs, and the input search really doesn't allow for the kind of search I am looking for. with the following snippet, the input search filters the text for exactly what is typed into the input filed:

```
 <form class="ui-filterable">
        <input id="myFilter" data-type="search"></input>
    </form>
    <div data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter">
    <p id="one">This is paragraph one or 1; it's not number 2</p>
    <p id="two">Next is two too 2</p>
    <p id="three">Three 3 is after 2</p>
    <p id="four">Finally is 4 four but not two</p>
    </div>
```

currently, an input of "paragraph 1" would not even filter to just p#one as the string "paragraph 1" does not appear in the text exactly. how do I go about adding conjunction and disjunction into the search capabilities to be able to search, for example, for paragraphs that just contain '"paragraph" AND "2"' or '"three" OR "2"'? I assume i would need to use regex with && and || to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/jreh3zhc/7/

```
var $paras = $('p');

$('#myFilter').on('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        vals = $this.val().toLowerCase().trim().split(' '),
        $found = $paras.filter(function (i, p) {
            var words = $(p).text().toLowerCase().split(' ');
            return vals.every(function (val) {
                return ~words.indexOf(val);
            });
        });
    $found.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    $paras.not($found).css('backgroundColor', '');
});
```

for `OR` instead of `AND` you should use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)